# Redirect direct registration page access by .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess-configuration, registration

I would like to redirect registration page to homepage by using `.htaccess` now my code is redirecting to `/component/users/?view=login&Itemid=437` which is login page. I would like to make registration and front-end login page not accessible for users.

So the target is to redirect `/component/users/?view=login&Itemid=437` and `/index.php?option=com_users&view=registration&Itemid=999` to "403 error page"

```
# RewriteBase /

# Disable calls to user registration ("register", this url ends with: view=registration))
# Send all blocked request to homepage, use Flag [F] for 403 Forbidden error!
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (view=registration) [NC]
RewriteRule .* index.php [F]

## Begin - Joomla! core SEF Section.
#
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
#
# If the requested path and file is not /index.php and the request
# has not already been internally rewritten to the index.php script
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php
# and the requested path and file doesn't directly match a physical file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# and the requested path and file doesn't directly match a physical folder
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# internally rewrite the request to the index.php script
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
#
## End - Joomla! core SEF Section.
```

Comment: I understand that you would like to do that with .htaccess, but may I ask why you do not want to do it within Joomla itself with making these pages available only for already registered users, or custom groups, or for admins only?

Comment: @Zollie have done it already but users can access `www.mypage.com/component/users/?view=login&Itemid=437` but public users can access it anyway by inputting this link to their web browser.

Comment: You can try any Joomla site. Some are locked somehow but some are still accessible. For example `http://www.moghees.co.uk/index.php?option=com_users&view=registration&Itemid=999` or `http://noblebrand.pl/index.php?option=com_users&view=registration&Itemid=999`

Comment: Yes, I understand you now. I’ll check this a bit more.

Comment: @Zollie so basically by adding `/index.php?option=com_users&view=registration&Itemid=999`to domain you will be on registration page or it will redirect to login page. But some websites like `https://www.linux.com/` or `https://www.guggenheim.org/` restricted access. So it drops an error or redirecting to another page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really want to close out visitors from users pages, then maybe you can also create a [system plugin](https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Creating_a_Plugin_for_Joomla) and `onAfterroute` event you could use something like the following code:

```
public function onAfterRoute()
{
    if ($this->app->getRouter()->getVar('option') === 'com_users')
    {
        $guestRedirectUrl = '/index.php';
        $this->app->redirect($guestRedirectUrl, $status = 303);
    }
}
```

(if you use it on a live webserver, the leading slash is not needed in the redirect url).

Or another version, as @Sharky has suggested, the following is more effective on sef urls:

```
if ($this->app->input->get('view') === 'registration')
{
    // let's redirect...
}
```

This is just a sudden idea on this, instead of using .htaccess for redirect. From the router you can get `Itemid` or `view` too, so it can work on more precise condition too like:

`if ($this->app->getRouter()->getVar('view') === 'registration')` and on many other versions of conditions. if sef urls are used this will not work on those pages, however this will:

```
$pagevars = $this->app->getRouter()->getVars();
if ($pagevars['option'] === 'com_users' && $pagevars['Itemid'] === '437')
{
    // do redirect...
}
```

(Itemid should be changed to your registration page's Itemid of course).

(**Itemid** and **option** (component name) is available via router too even if someone uses sef urls).

**Sidenote:** creating a plugin for these kind of small tasks sounds quite stupid, but it is not if you can/would later use this same custom system plugin of yours to do few other things on your site via a system plugin. It comes handy at those times too.

Comment: Better to use Input for operations like this. `$this->app->getRouter()->getVar('view')` returns `NULL` on URLs like `/component/users/login`. Also remove leading slash before `index.php`, it causes redirect to root directory even if Joomla is installed in a subfolder.

Comment: @Sharky - thanks for the comments! It could work with using input too, maybe even better, I have not really compared. The leading slash is only if someone is trying these on localhost, where without slash it does not work. However I would update the answer with these short but important notes.

Comment: Please do test your code. `$this->app->getRouter()->getVar('Itemid')` returns `NULL` on `/component/users/login?Itemid=437`. I tried this on localhost (XAMPP) and leading slash was not needed but having it caused the redirect to root directory.

Comment: @Sharky - my code is tested, my friend. The particular Itemid is just an example in the code and that itemid is just what the OP's own Itemid (437) if you read his question above. Your Itemid of your login page (given by your router) is different as usually for everybody else. The code has to be customized with your own given Itemid(given by the router not by you) as I noticed in my answer. I tested the code on my localhost and I get the results what I wrote. I use WAMP server on localhost and it does not work without leading slash on my local host (but it depends on server settings too).

Comment: @Sharky - my registration page Itemid is 1138 for example...

Comment: @Sharky - if you var_dump your router $vars you will know what your registration page Itemid is.

Comment: Do `var_dump()` on `$this->app->getRouter()->getVars()` and `$this->app->input->getArray()` and you'll see that router is missing vars in some cases, including `Itemid`. Secondly, using `Itemid` here isn't valid anyways because it can be manipulated easily.

Comment: @Smarty - yes, for sure, my friend.